# Delphi MAKEFOURCC troubles

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm struggling with this code:

```
MAKEFOURCC('R','I','F','F');
```

The function is a translation from C++, and in Delphi it should be like this:

```
function MAKEFOURCC(const ch0: AnsiChar;
                  const ch1: AnsiChar;
                  const ch2: AnsiChar;
                  const ch3: AnsiChar): FOURCC; inline;
  begin
    Result:= DWORD(Ord(ch0)) or
            (DWORD(Ord(ch1)) shl 8) or
            (DWORD(Ord(ch2)) shl 16) or
            (DWORD(Ord(ch3)) shl 24);
  end;
```

Now, this will result in (big-endian) $46464952, which is wrong.
It should be $52494646.

Looking at Microsoft's explanation the code for this macro is:

```
#define MAKEFOURCC(ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3)  \ 
((DWORD)(BYTE)(ch0) | ((DWORD)(BYTE)(ch1) << 8) |  \ 
((DWORD)(BYTE)(ch2) << 16) | ((DWORD)(BYTE)(ch3) << 24 ));
```

reversing the order ch3, ch2, ch1 and ch0 results in the correct value:

```
Result:= DWORD(Ord(ch3)) or
         (DWORD(Ord(ch2)) shl 8) or
         (DWORD(Ord(ch1)) shl 16) or
         (DWORD(Ord(ch0)) shl 24);
```

Now what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Searching for `delphi MAKEFOURCC` turns up many results for me. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Jerry I searched all of them, and all comes to the first translation. And as I can see in the C++ code, there should be nothing wrong with that. The same counts for macro FCC, which is an alias and gives the same results. Now, what I'm thinking is Microsoft gave a bad explanation , or the Delphi clan never tested this translated macro from MS.

Comment: The translation is identical, and both the C++ and Delphi versions produce the same exact results. There is no way that Delphi's result will be different than the C++ results given the same input, and if you think it does you're mistaken.

Comment: @Ken White I'm just reading the compiler and file header results and that is what I'm dealing with, not my eyes nor the code. You may try it. Translating the result will be "FFIR" not "RIFF". Or is it a flaw in Delphi XE7?

Comment: It doesn't matter what value you're seeing. Your claim that the two functions produce different output given the same input is simply wrong. They are identical, and on the Windows OS will produce identical results. Delphi does not do anything different with those operations than the C++ code does, and it does not produce different results.

Comment: @ Ken White. I'm not claiming they differ: They give the same results, but the wrong ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the impact of endianess on the resulting FOURCC value.

You state that $46464952 is the 'wrong' result, but it is the *right* result, based on the documentation from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/fourcc-codes

Note that this highlights the little-endian nature of Windows, with the result that the FOURCC encoding for the string 'YUY2' is in fact `2YUY`. When encoded as a 32-bit numeric byte order is reversed as compared to the endian-agnostic string representation.

The FOURCC encoding of YUY2 is $59555932 which when reversed for little-endian representation yields $32595559 which is the result obtained from the original and literal implementation of `MAKEFOURCC()` in your post.

i.e. the result that you think is wrong is in fact right.

The requirements for **storage** representation in a particular file format are very often independent of the in-memory representation.  The fact that the WAV header (and indeed the FourCC specification generally) requires Big Endian representation doesn't alter the fact that your original MakeFourCC implementation is correct.  It just means that you also need to reverse the bytes when storing the FourCC in a WAV header block.

Comment: Yes, for the FOURCC GUID used in  the biCompression member of the BITMAPINFOHEADER. But not for big-endian used in the RIFF header used in the WAVE header format, I think. Just open the file "Windows Information Bar.wav" and you will see the header starts with "RIFF" ($52494646) and not "FFIR" ($46464952).

Comment: @Toka the requirements for storage representation in a particular file format are very often independent of the in-memory representation.  The fact that the WAV header requires Big Endian representation doesn't alter the fact that your original MakeFourCC implementation is correct.  It just means that you need to reverse the bytes when storing in a WAV header block.

Comment: @ Deltics That's just the point. I did reverse them and then it's correct...  I was just wondering why that is, because the MS documentation and headers don't mention this. I hoped someone could explain why the macro is not altered to write the correct result as it should be. Thank you.

Comment: @Toka I _did_ explain and this _is_ highlighted in the MS documentation, as referenced.  The macro already provides the correct result.  On Windows that result is LITTLE endian.  The correct representation in a WAV file header is BIG endian, so you need to reverse the bytes when persisting to/from a WAV header.  The **value** is the same in both cases; the **representations** are different but _both correct_ in their separate and different contexts.

Comment: Thank you. I will sort this out, because until now Media Foundation writes the wrong header format this way as suggested by MS, and the right header as I stated. I'll let you know what the results are, asap.

Comment: @Tok  - Perhaps you should ask a question about media foundation then. `fs.Write(fcc, 4)` writes "RIFF" in human readable format to a file where `fs` is a file stream and `fcc` is a DWORD which is assigned `fcc := MAKEFOURCC('R', 'I', 'F', 'F');`.

Comment: @Deltics - The last paragraph is wrong misleaded by the questioner.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - how so ?  The WAV header format does indeed stipulate big-endian FourCC (and in general, FourCC in storage is "human readable", i.e. big-endian int / 'string' format).  I'm concerned not to leave something misleading in the answer, but I don't see how it is.  Can you explain ?

Comment: The macro reverses the bytes, when written to a file as a dword the api reverses it again because of endianness. So the programmer does not have to reverse anything. If it is not what the last paragraph says, it is not that the answer is wrong but what I understand from it is wrong.

Comment: Ok. There are a lot of misunderstandings about the structure of a RIFF header. According to MS the chunks are little-endian and that explains my pain, because a lot of so written articles are wrong about this. I think Sertac Akyuz explained it correct.. Indeed my last suggestion in the last paragraph is wrong! but I wrote it as a suggestion why this is correct while debugging and wrong when written to file. It has something to do with the Delphi MMSystem API function WriteToFile. In Studio this method works correct, but not always in Delphi :-(

Comment: @Tok - I should note that technically my comment is not correct either. It should probably rather read, "since the fourcc is formed into a DWORD, it is reversed in a little endian environment". The point remains same though, you don't reverse it yourself.